# Collision Detection for arbitrarily sized, positioned and rotated rectangles in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection

I'm working with xna in C# and in my game I will have a variety of space ships flying all over the place. They will each have an arbitrary rotation, size and position in space and I need a method to determine when they collide. Ideally the method would take two Rectangles, two doubles and two Vector2s for size, rotation and position respectively and return a boolean that indicates whether they have intersected or not.

Comment: Are you asking us to write a method for you or do you have one you've started on already?

Comment: I'm looking for anything. If you can write a method for me, that would be awesome, but algorithms or concepts would be useful as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at these links:

[Collision Detection Overview](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series2D/Coll_Detection_Overview.php)
[Collision Detection Matrices](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series2D/Coll_Detection_Matrices.php)
[Putting Collision Detection Into Practice](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series2D/Putting_CD_into_practice.php)

They show you a way to do pixel-based collision detection, which is more accurate than rectangle-based for irregularly shaped objects.

#### Update 2021-01-17 (Martin Senne)

Links of XNA have moved to

[XNA](https://github.com/SimonDarksideJ/XNAGameStudio)
[XNA - Collision](https://github.com/SimonDarksideJ/XNAGameStudio/wiki/Collision)

Comment: @kyralessa: you almost never want to do pixel perfect collisions in games. For instance, he is making a game with rocketships. With pixel perfect collision it would mean if 1 pixel of the wing of a rocket would touch 1 pixel of the tip of his spaceship it would explode. Usually you define a collision box to be a much smaller region inside the objects. This looks and feels much better.

Comment: @MartinSenne My abject apologies that links from *ten years ago* aren't working anymore.    Feel free to suggest updated links.

Comment: https://github.com/simondarksidej/XNAGameStudio/wiki/RiemersArchiveOverview ? :D (can't undo the downvote as long as the your answer is not updated :-O )

Answer (score 2):

You could also consider just using an out of the box solution for this and integrating something like the Farseer Physics Engine:
http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

These rectangles you describe are called OBB (Oriented Bounding Boxes)

The way to do collisions between them is using the 'Separating axis theorem'

A really nice page describing it in detail with lots of pictures can be found [here](http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html)

Comment: They're not axis-aligned if they're rotated around.

Comment: You are very right of course. I meant OBB. The theory still stands for those as well ;^)